# IOS LaunchImage not show on Xcode 6.

Tags: ios, xcode, splash-screen

I already set up LaunchImage on Xcode but still got Black screen when i open the app like image below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Anyone knows how to fix this?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your .plist file about the value of Launch Screen Image. Maybe you have a wrong value there.

Comment: if i add Launch screen interface file base name on .plist i would got white screen with app name and if i delete it i got the black one.

Comment: There are more options about launch screen except the Launch screen interface file base name such as Launch Image or Launch Image(iPad) etc. Check if you set somewhere some of them and delete row Launch screen interface file base name from property list file if exists.

Answer (score 0):

Check your launch image asset may be you are having wrong image sizes or you are missing the image for that device. You can select the device from attributes inspector & add proper size images for that device[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Images.xcassets > LaunchImage > Select an image > Open Attribute Inspector.

Check if the "Expected Size" and the "Actual Size" of the all the launch images are same.

You can get black screen if the actual and expected sizes are different.